# $z\overline{w}\ne 1 $ Prove that $|\frac{w-z}{1-\overline{w}z}|\le 1|$ if $|z|\le 1$ and $|w|\le 1 $

Tags: complex-analysis

$z\overline{w} \ne 1 $ Prove that $|\frac{w-z}{1-\overline{w}z}|\le 1$ if $|z|\le 1$ and $|w|\le 1 $. How to proceed this question?

Comment: I would suggest looking at $|1-\overline wz|^2-|w-z|^2$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left|\frac{w-z}{1-\overline{w}z}\right|\le 1\iff|w-z|\le|1-\overline{w}z|\iff|w-z|^2\le|1-\overline{w}z|^2\\\iff(w-z)(\overline{w}-\overline{z})\le(1-w\overline{z})(1-\overline{w}z)\iff(1-z\overline{z})(1-w\overline{w})\ge0\\\iff|z|\le1,|w|\le 1~~~~~\text{or}~~~~~|z|\ge1,|w|\ge1$$

Comment: [+1] Very good answer.